# 'Set' in Components of Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to use [Set](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/977/Controller-Methods#set-979) function inside components in cake php ?

```
class TestComponent extends Object
{
  //etc

 $this->set('User', $user); 

 }
```

I am getting an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method TestComponent::set()
```

How this can be corrected ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function startup($controller) { $this->controller = $controller }
function something() {
    $this->controller->set('User',$user);
}
```

Cake passes the Controller reference to the startup function of a Component. You need to keep a reference in your component to use later in custom functions.

See here http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/996/Creating-Components#MVC-Class-Access-Within-Components-998

Comment: How to set AppController here ?

Comment: What do you mean by AppController?

Comment: one minor thing: always use the correct argument syntax: `public function startup(Controller $controller) {}` - ok, for 2.x anyway (he seems to be using 1.3 still, sry)

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the time Component methods are called from controllers, you can return the value from functions in controller.
If you want set variables for your view layer then this can be used

```
$this->Controller->set('varForView',varValue);
```

This is because components have a class variable for the Controller instance from where it was instantiated.