# How to use "set" in component especially in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to use Set function inside components in cake php especially in cake version 1.3 ?

```
class DevicesComponent extends Object
{
   function startup($controller) 
  { 
    $this->controller = $controller; 
  }
  function push()
  {
      $this->set('data', $data); 
      $this->controller->set('data', $data); 
  }


 }
```

I am getting the following error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DevicesComponent::set() .

I checked the existing same questions but the links not available ['Set' in Components of Cake PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229710/set-in-components-of-cake-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it removing the `$this->set('data', $data)` from your `push` function:

```
function push()
{
     $this->controller->set('data', $data); 
}
```

And using this instead of the `startup` function:

```
public function initialize(){

    $this->controller =& $controller;

}
```

Comment: yes i done the same thing..  class DevicesComponent extends Object
{
 function startup($controller) 
 { 
  $this->controller = $controller; 
 }
  function push()
    {
  $this->controller->set('data', $data); 
   }
}

Throwing error as "Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object "

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? It's incorrect. Components don't even have a beforeFilter() callback.

Comment: @Steve The same case is not working.. when i am calling through the cron jobs.. what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line `$this->set('data', $data);` and the error will be gone. You already have the correct statement in next line to set view var through the controller instance `$this->controller->set('data', $data);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,it may works..

```
  function startup(&$controller) 
  { 
    $this->controller = $controller; 
  }
```

And in the push function

```
  function push()
  {
     $this->controller->set('data', $data); 
  }
```